# Google's time fence using Awareness API is not reliable

Tags: android, google-awareness

I am building an SDK that is using Google Awareness API.

I have some actions that need to be executed based on different schedules for each day, also when the app is backgrounded - a perfect match for Google's [FenceClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/FenceClient) or so I thought.

The problem is that the notifications I'm getting are not really related to times I configured in the fence - sometimes the notifications are minutes/hours late and sometimes I'm not getting those notifications at all.

What's weirder is that all Google's examples are still using the deprecated[GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client).

Technical issues:

- I defined these two permissions in the manifest:

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
>
> uses-permission
>   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"

- Awareness is activated in the Google console and I have the API keys defined in the manifest.
- I tried to use both (one of them in each time) *BroadcastReceiver* and *JobIntentService* using *PendingIntent.getBroadcast* and *PendingIntent.getService*. Both of them also defied in the manifest.
- I'm building the *AwarenessFence* like this: `TimeFence.inIntervalOfDay(dayOfWeek, TimeZone.getDefault(), startTimeOfDayMillis, stopTimeOfDayMillis);` start and stop times are in milliseconds since the start of the day.
- `fenceClient.updateFences` is completed successfully.